# How to install Ubuntu 16.04 using iso file?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I am using an Ubuntu 10.04 system, but now it is not at all supported, so i would like to install Ubuntu 16.04.For that I just downloaded the 16.04 iso file. I would like to install 16.04, so what should I do? can somebody help?
I prefer making and using a bootable flash drive but don't know how!. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a friend of mine has written a post on his blog which I feel would be very helpful to you as you are using Ubuntu 10.04. Here is the [post](https://geekyshacklebolt.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/how-to-create-bootable-usb-using-cli/).

Also, I feel that if you would have searched it on the internet it would surely have given you many solutions. I also found a software readily available and open-source, namely [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

There isn't any hard and fast rule that you have to only use this application, you can use any mentioned [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/rufus/?platform=linux).
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: yes i tried unetbootin i booted it when i tap install it says first load kernel

Comment: @ArjunKShibu please can you elaborate, I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

At last found the problem!,it was the problem with the .iso file. I downloaded the "Ubuntu 16.04.5 Server" instead of "Ubuntu 16.04.5 Desktop".I created a bootable Flash drive using UNetbootin and installed it. However 16.04 LTS works fine on my PC, really enjoying it! Thanks to everyone who spend their time to find me an answer, sorry too as it was my mistake! :)